# WordPress 'menu_class' assigned to wrapping div

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

According to [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/), the 'menu_class' property is supposed to add the class to the ul element. It odesn't..

Here is the inspector: 
[inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3Jiq.png)

The menu code:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
  'menu'            => 'main-menu',
  'container'       => '',
  'container_class' => 'false',
  'container_id'    => '',
  'menu_class'      => 'navbar', 
  'echo'            => true,
  'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
  'before'          => '',
  'after'           => '',
  'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
  'depth'           => 0,
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Did you defined any menu in admin>appearance>menus ? There is a bug
   in Wordpress menu that if you have not defined any menu its will be
   display the default menu by default settings.
2. If you want to using bootstrap, Don't let Wordpress to create container and element and create your own that stuff by setting the "items_wrap" to '%3$s'.